# Recurring issue with not being able to use MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, xampp

I am a total noob at this, so I need to start off with saying that I barely know what I'm doing. I'm taking a highschool level course in web development, mainly html, css and javascript. I have a website running on wordpress with my database created in phpMyAdmin. It's supposed to work "with no issue", according to the course I shouldn't have to know anything about databases etc yet (that's next course).

Either way, my course is online and the teachers never answer soooo I'm asking for your help now, my error log is below.

If all else fails, does anyone know how to save all my work on wordpress? pages and articles etc.

I used XAMPP/MariaDB without issue in august and september. Then I had a break and got back to it in november, this time with a new hard drive - so a new installation. Previously it was on D-drive, but I re-installed it on C-drive. At some point I also updated to windows 11. After this the issues showed up, maybe after a week or so.

Installation went smoothly, no obvious problems. Setting up database and wordpress also no issue. Then suddenly one time when I started MariaDB I got the same error message as below. I followed som tutorial on youtube (copying backup files to data folder), did not work. Re-installed, worked fine for a day or two, same problem again. Went through this a couple more times, installed on D-drive hoping for change, but still the same. And here I am now.

I get stopped from posting because of the length of the error log, so here it is as a [pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RW3gZhiFNlmQ_wSVxeWlNkhHdAW_7bsR/view?usp=sharing). But the issue seems to be something of this?

```
2023-12-18 14:37:10 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=258] log sequence number 3401025 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 2495839.
2023-12-18 14:37:10 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2023-12-18 14:37:10 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
```

Comment: Oh yes, and if it seems stupid of me not to have tried any fixes myself, it is because I can't even quite understand what the problem is.

Comment: First of all, you're using MariaDB, not MySQL. The error log shows that. MariaDB is not MySQL, and they're not compatible. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, but both products have changed a lot since then. I've edited to make it clear you're using MariaDB.

Comment: The error log is showing evidence of corruption in either data files or log files. This can be quite difficult to recover from. Probably a question to post on dba.stackexchange.com, not on Stack Overflow. The most common solution is "restore from most recent backup" but if you don't have one, there are data recovery solutions that _might_ help (but no guarantees). Worst case scenario is that you've lost the database.

Comment: I suggest you read some of the answers posted on dba related to the error keywords "log sequence in future": https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=log+sequence+in+future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a consequence of either two instances of MariaDB running on the same data dir or copying partial files and expecting them to work.

The later XAMPP 8.0.30, 8.1.25, 8.2.12 include [MariaDB-10.4.32](https://github.com/ApacheFriends/xampp-build/pull/32/files#diff-1c03ce3a87da52231892c6ba15623f4814954bf693bccdc6085e8d687d676893).

I suggest removing all XAMPP versions, and the datadir on both drives. Install a new XAMPP version.

- Go through the installation slowly.
- Don't mess with database files directly.
- Don't take copies of database files while the MariaDB services is running.
- If taking a copy of database files, while MariaDB isn't running, do as a full set, and restore as a full set.
- Read mariadb error log before taking any corrective action. Ask on [dba exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com) is you don't follow what it means.

Do continue with this, there are hard points in IT, normally learnt by experiences like this, but its genuinely worth while and enjoyable.

Comment: For anyone with the same issue, this here worked. However a few notes:
I had done the re-installation this way with different versions of XAMPP several times. Although, I had not tried the XAMPP 8.0.30 specifically, which I used this time. I also turned off UAC this time, which I had not before. Things have been running smoothly since!